# Метод message.send — Captcha needed (VK API)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, авторизация

Необходимо отсылать пользователю личное сообщение ВКонтакте посредством PHP-скрипта. Согласно документации, метод `messages.send` доступен только Standalone-приложениям. Однако на выходе (при запуске скрипта с токеном отправителя) имеем проверку Captcha .

Насколько я понимаю, есть привязка к региону или IP, так как токен отправителя принадлежит одной стране (одному IP), а скрипт с вышеупомянутым токеном запускается на сервере другой страны. Есть ли возможность зарегистрировать токен непосредственно на сервере, или есть другой механизм обхода?

Comment: Да, привязка именно по региону. А что собственно мешает с сервера его сгенерировать?

Comment: Мне признаться не совсем понятно как его получить, дело в том что ответ с нужным токеном для standalone приложений api направляет на "внутренний" адрес т.е. на https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html

Comment: Забыл про редирект, это слегка усложняет жизнь. Как на счет того чтобы просто зарегистрировать токен из той страны, где сервер? VPN, proxy и.т.д

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. *VK API* не пускает выполнять запросы. 
У меня хостинг (сервер) в Нидерландах.

Решил проблему так:

Установил расширение хрома *VPN-HOLA*, открыл *VK* в браузере, в расширении выбрал Нидерланды. *VK* предупредил, что я из подозрительного места, я все подтвердил, авторизовался.

После этого работа из скрипта с *VK API* стала обрабатываться нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Искал решение на эту проблему долгое время , случайно она решилась после того как сайт на котором работал скрипт с VK API хостер перенёс с сервера Украины на сервер в Германию.
Скрипт перестал работать и стал запрашивать при первом же обращении к VK каптчу.
Но пока сайт стоял на сервере в Украине всё работало нормально,установил этот скрипт на другой сайт который находился на сервере в Украине и вуаля - всё работает.
Спрашивается почему? Да потому ,что токен получал пользователь у которого IP был Украинский и скрипт работал с Украинского IP.
Что я сделал - получил токен используя IP Германии.
Зашёл через Германский прокси сервер в ВК,получил токен,ввёл в настройках скрипта новый токен и всё заработало.
Отсюда делаем выводы ,что токен нужно получать с той же страны где работает скрипт или программа.
Если не совпадают то срабатывает система защиты ВК и просят ввести каптчу.